# How to make the contents of a box overlap eachother

Tags: html, css

How do I make the divs of `.slides` all be in the same exact position and "overlap" each other? So they are all like on top of each other kind of

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="pics">img 1</div>
      <div class="pics">img 2</div>
      <div class="pics">img 3</div>
      <div class="pics">img 4</div>
      <div class="pics">img 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can use grid it make overlapping elements pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

make position absolute of the elements, it will overlap

```css
.slides{
  position: relative;
}
.slides .pics{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
  <div class="content">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="pics">img 1</div>
      <div class="pics">img 2</div>
      <div class="pics">img 3</div>
      <div class="pics">img 4</div>
      <div class="pics">img 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```